# Hide Div onClick when clicking outside the child div | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I currently have a a parent div and a child div in the middle of the parent div. I want to be able to close the parent div only on clicking outside of the child div. How would I go about doing this? I have my code currently set up as below, with the triggerParentUpdate to set true or false whether to show div.

```
<div onClick={this.props.triggerParentUpdate} className="signupModalContainer">
    <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <form action="action_page.php">
            <div className="container">
            <button onClick={this.props.triggerParentUpdate} type="button" className="closebtn">X</button>                             
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

the onclick function in the first div (className="signupModalContainer") makes it so that when I click that div or any of the child divs, all the divs close. if I take that onclick function out, then the divs close via the closebtn.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the Javascript code as well; as it is now, it will be hard for people to help.

Comment: Did you try  to apply  `event.stopPropagation();` to child div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a handler for the child div's `onClick` event handler, which stops the propagation/bubbling up of the event to the parent.

Refer to [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method for more info.

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  handleCloseButton = e => {
    // This stops the event from bubbling up.
    // So it won't trigger the parent div's "onClick" to fire.
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.triggerParentUpdate(e);
  }

  render () {
    // ...
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.triggerParentUpdate} className="signupModalContainer">
          <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <form action="action_page.php">
                  <div className="container">
                  <button onClick={this.handleCloseButton} type="button" className="closebtn">X</button>                             
                  </div>
              </form> 
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is also easy to check for clicks in the parent

```
   const handleParentClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
      console.log('parent clicked');
      //  your logic here
    }
  };
```